# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) but only in one computer

Tags: json, python-3.x

**UPDATE:** I can replicate this issue with US IP, i don't know why though...

I can't loads json from https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1 using this code:

```js
import urllib.request as urllib
import json

user_url = 'https://www.instagram.com/instagram/?__a=1'
response = urllib.urlopen(user_url)

data = json.loads(response.read())
igtv_count = data['graphql']['user']['edge_felix_video_timeline']['count']
print("IGTV: " + str(igtv_count) + " Video(s)")
```

The problem is, I can run this code in other computer with python 3.7 **except mine**. It always give me this error message:

```js
data = json.loads(response.read())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I don't know what I did wrong. I've done a lot of research on trying to resolve the jsondecodeerror. However, I'm not finding a solution. Usually the solution is about UTF-8 Decode, again it's work too but not for my computer. Thanks

Comment: Check what you obtained from response: `print(response.read())`. Maybe your IP is banned?

Comment: @AndrejKesely it return HTTPResponse, i don't think my ip got banned, because i can open the url with browser.